# Calling undeclared function template from inside another function template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, function-templates

I am learning about templates in C++ and so trying out different examples. One such example whose output i am unable to understand is given below:

```
template<typename T> void func(T p) {
g<T>(p); //ERROR
g(p);    //NO ERROR?
}


int main()
{

}
```

When i try to compile the above code snippet, i get [error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LCVVFyhg22l65xNS) saying:

```
prog.cc: In function 'void func(T)':
prog.cc:2:1: error: 'g' was not declared in this scope
    2 | g<T>(p); //ERROR
      | ^
prog.cc:2:4: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
    2 | g<T>(p); //ERROR
      |    ^
```

My questions are:

1. Why i am getting this error?
2. Why i am getting the error only for the statement `g<T>(p);` and not for `g(p);`? I thought that writing `g(p);` is equivalent to `g<T>(p);` since due to template argument deduction the template parameter for `g` will be deduced to `T`.

Comment: unless g is also a templated function or class, compiler shall not know what g<T> means at that point.  look up SFINAE for some justification on the behavior- it makes for some very powerful compile-time capabilities.

Comment: `g(p);` might be found by ADL. For template notation case, **any** (but with same name) previous template declaration would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Case 1

Here we consider the statement: `g<T>(p);`

```
template<typename T> void func(T p) {
g<T>(p); //ERROR
}
int main()
{

}
```

In the above code snippet the name `g` is a **unqualified dependent name**. And from [**source**: two phase lookup](https://www.amazon.in/Templates-Complete-Guide-David-Vandevoorde/dp/0321714121):

> During the first phase, while **parsing** a template **unqualified dependent names** are looked up using the ordinary lookup rules. For unqualified dependent names, the initial ordinary lookup—while not complete—is used to decide whether the name is a template.

Now lets apply this to the statement `g<T>(p);`. When parsing the function template `func`, the statement `g<T>(p);` is encountered. Since `g` is a dependent qualified name, according to the above quoted statement, the name `g` is **looked up** using **ordinary lookup rules**. This is so that the compiler can decide whether the name `g` is a template. But since there is no declaration for a function template named `g` before this point, the first angle bracket `<` is treated as a *less than symbol* and hence produces the error you mentioned. Also, note that **ADL** is done in *second phase*. But for that to happen we must first successfully parse the generic definition of function `func`.[**source**: C++ Templates: The Complete guide: Page 250 second last paragraph]

Note that compilers are allowed to delay error until instantiation which is why some compilers compiles your code without any error. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z5z9nxa44).

##### Case 2

Here we consider the statement `g(p);`.

```
template<typename T> void func(T p) {
g(p); // NO ERROR
}
int main()
{

}
```

In this case also, the name `g` is an **unqualified dependent name**. So according to the quoted statement from the beginning of my answer, the name `g` is **looked up** using ordinary lookup rules. But since there is no `g` **visible** at this point we have an error. There are two things to note here:

1. Since this time you have not explicitly(by using the angle brackets) called `g`, there is no **syntax error**.
2. And since there are no syntax error in this case and there are no **POI** for `func` in your program, so here there are no errors to delay and the program compiles fine. However, if you instantiate `func` then you'll get error at instantiation time saying `g` was not declared.

Comment: Notice that in case 2, there are no errors to delay. And it is really at the instantiation that error might occurs, (as `g` might be properly declared/defined later for such type).

Comment: @Jarod42 Can you elaborate on why there are no errors to delay in case 2. I mean since during the first phase(for `g(p);`) when it is found that there is no visible `g` so shouldn't this be an error saying g was not declared?

Comment: There is ADL, so `void g(MyObject){}` can be declared after. (especially if `g` is a point of customization). and so `h(MyObject{});` would be fine [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oK75asTWo).

Comment: And [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5fe1ceo35) for valid `g<T>(p)` call with unrelated previous template `g` function.

Comment: @Jarod42 As i understand now, ADL happens in second phase. And in the quoted book i read that *"But for that(ADL) to happen we must first successfully parse the generic definition of function func"* which happens in first phase. Since there was no visible declaration for `g` in first phase, i think it should produce error just like in Case 1 of this answer. Can you explain? Thanks

Comment: First phase of [two-phase_lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/two-phase_lookup) just checks syntax. and from [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), since C++20, Case 1 is not a syntax error neither.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think i got it now. In case 2 of this answer it is also mentioned that there are no syntax error for case 2. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

template uses a [Two-phase name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/two-phase_lookup).

> First, at the point of the template definition, the template is checked for syntax.

and so `g(p);` is correct (from syntax point of view) (assuming a function `g` found by [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)).

For `g<T>(p);`, we have (until C++20):

> Although a function call can be resolved through ADL even if ordinary lookup finds nothing, a function call to a function template with explicitly-specified template arguments requires that there is a declaration of the template found by ordinary lookup (otherwise, it is a syntax error to encounter an unknown name followed by a less-than character)

`g<T>(p);` is not correct, (as parsed only as `(g < T) > p;` (`T` is a type, so it is wrong)).

If there exists any template function `g`, then `g` might be considered as template, and code would be correct from syntax point of view (even if template parameter won't match).